# Compile an alphabetic list of character strings from three columns in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, concatenation, transpose

I have a google spreadsheet that looks like the following:

```
Mediation 1 Mediation 2 Mediation 3 Mediation 4
   ELL        TIME        Health       Time         
   Health       ELL        TIME         Behavior
```

I have constructed a "Mediation All" that creates a comma separated list of each mediation assigned. It looks like the following :

```
Mediation 1 Mediation 2 Mediation 3 Mediation 4       Mediation All
   ELL        TIME        Health       Time         ELL, Time, Health, 
   Health       ELL        TIME         Behavior    Health, Ell, Time, Behavior
```

The code I am using to generate the Mediation All is the following:

```
=iferror(sort(join(",",filter(indirect(concatenate(address(row(),match("Mediation 1",A$1:JA$1,0),4),":",address(row(),match("Mediation 2",A$1:JA$1,0),4))),indirect(concatenate(address(row(),match("Mediation 1 ",A$1:JA$1,0),4),":",address(row(),match("Mediation 2",A$1:JA$1,0),4)))<>""))))
```

The code above omits Mediation 3 and Mediation 4 that I am including here.

I would like the list of mediations to be alphabetized so that the

```
ELL, Time, Health, Time
```

is replaced with

```
ELL, Health, Time
```

and

```
Health, ELL, Time, Behavior
```

becomes

```
Behavior, ELL, Health, Time
```

This makes it easier to input the data. The person putting in the data doesn't have to put the same Mediation into the same column and row.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is not clear to me. First of all I can not get your formula to work. But let's assume you have created Mediation All.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is not clear to me. First of all I can not get your formula to work. But let's assume you have created Mediation All. Do you just want this in one cell just in alpha order? Do you want the existing data under Mediation1 through 4 to actually change to alpha order? What do you want to end up with. Both are possible. Could you clarify. It would also help if you could share your spreadsheet.

Comment: I would like to to be in one cell, just in alpha order. I don't want the data under Mediation1 through 4 to change to alpha order. I just want for the cells under the column Mediation All to contain all the Mediations but in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short formula: `=join(",",transpose(Sort(UNIQUE(transpose(A2:D2)))))`

- [`Unique`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) filters out repeated values on **rows**
- Since values are in columns, we have to [`transpose`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) the values
- For some reason, we can't use `join` without re-transposing the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

@daniel formula seems to work. If you do not want 'TIME' and 'Time' both returned, change the formula to:

```
=join(",",TRANSPOSE(Sort(UNIQUE(LOWER(transpose(A2:D2))))))
```

However, this will return everything in lower case (ell,health,time).
Or, if you are Ok with what you have already concatenated in a single cell and just want to remove dups and put it in alpha order use:

=JOIN( ", ", SORT(unique(lower(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT( $A5, ",")))))))

Where $A5 is your concatenated cell.